# How to use dd on WSL?

Tags: unix, dump, windows-subsystem-for-linux

How can I used the `dd` command to dump the contents of a removable disk in WSL?

When I run,

```
dd if=/mnt/d of=sdDump bs=512 count=1
```

I get the error `dd: error reading '/mnt/d': Is a directory`

I followed the [steps shown here](https://superuser.com/a/1209701) to mount the disk:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/d
sudo mount -t drvfs D: /mnt/d
```

Doing this allows me to see the files on the disk via `ls`, but running `dd` yields the above error.

Comment: For the "if" argument, use the device you passed to the mount command, not the name of the directory you mounted it to.

Comment: @pcjr Hi, could you elaborate? What do you mean by "use the device"?

Comment: Use block devices. Since WSL does not support them, I recommend [cygwin](https://cygwin.org/) or [cmder](https://cmder.net/). Please note you'll need to open a terminal as administrator, then run `dd if=/dev/sdb of=sdDump bs=512 count=1 status=progress`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is a category error in usage. `dd` doesn't work with directories, it works with files. The files can be [device files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_file) (like `/dev/sda` or `/dev/urandom` on Linux), or regular files (like `echo foo >> myfile.txt`). What you're trying to pass is a directory in a mounted filesystem.

Unfortunately, WSL doesn't seem to support accessing your block device files (i.e. it doesn't have `/dev`). You can follow [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/689) feature request on their issue tracker to see when they will add support.

Answer (score 10):

As @asad-saeeduddin has said, WSL doesn't have block level access, but that doesn't mean that you can't use dd on Windows!

I've found out that dd is part of the set of tools that are installed along with Git for Windows. After install you can find it in **C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\dd.exe**

The Windows equivalent to /dev/sda is \.\PHYSICALDRIVE0 and you can find the proper IDs for your local machine's devices with this command (also returns the sector sizes):

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_diskdrive | select Caption,DeviceID,BytesPerSector,InterfaceType,Size
```

Comment: In case it's not obvious, the command snippet is PowerShell, not Bash.

Answer (score -1):

The typical usage of the mount command is to specify what you want to mount (a *device*, on *nix a *device* is really just a special type of file) and where you want to mount it (a directory).  The `dd` command wants some type of file. In your example, `D:` is the *device*, so this is the argument you need to pass to `dd`:

```
dd if=D: of=sdDump bs=512 count=1
```

Disclaimer: I do not have WSL experience, but I have been using `mount` and  and `dd` for decades.

Comment: Unfortunately, i don't think `dd if=D:` will work; WSL doesn't have support for accessing the block device files.

Comment: any updates on this? maybe with WSL2 being available on Insider program with real linux kernel?